# How to update editText for data object in recycle view Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-edittext

I am new to android studio and just starter 1 month ago for learning it.

I currently try to written the app that has list of data class with name, price, quantity and unit cost.
I have done the recycle view and i am facing the problem that how to update the editText value whenever the user input the quantity in the data classs

Below are my data class code

```
data class food (val food: String, val price: Int, var quantity: Int, var cost: Int = price*quantity)

object ABC {
var food_List = listOf<food>(
    ABC ("A", 28 ,5) ,
    ABC ("B", 28, 0)
)}
```

Below are my recycle view adaptor

```
class customAdaptor (val context: Context, val food_List:List<food>):RecyclerView.Adapter<customAdaptor.ViewHolder>() {
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    val v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_layout,parent, false)
    return ViewHolder(v)
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return food_List.size
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val listused=  food_List[position]
    holder.setData(listused,position)
}

inner class ViewHolder (itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

    fun setData(listused: food?, pos: Int) {
        itemView.listFoodName.text = listused!!.food
        itemView.listUnitPrice.text =listused.price.toString()
        itemView.listUnitTotalPrice.text=listused.cost.toString()


    }
}}
```

Below are my mainactivity

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_page_budget)

    val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    layoutManager.orientation = LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL
    recyclerview.layoutManager = layoutManager


    val adapter = customAdaptor(this, ABC.food_List)
    recyclerview.adapter = adapter}
```

Below are my layout for card view.

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cardView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="270dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:id="@+id/listFoodName"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:id="@+id/listUnitPrice"/>
         <EditText
                  android:layout_width="50dp"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:textAlignment="center"
                  android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                  android:id="@+id/listQuantity"/>
        <TextView
                  android:layout_width="50dp"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:textAlignment="center"
                  android:id="@+id/listUnitTotalPrice"/> -->

    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Then i didnt know how to write the editText for the update.
Please help. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use this:

> editText.afterTextChanged{doSomethingWithText(it)}

Your code would be something like:

```
fun setData(listused: food?, pos: Int) {
    itemView.listFoodName.text =listused!!.food
    itemView.listUnitPrice.text =listused.price.toString()         
    itemView.listUnitTotalPrice.text=listused.cost.toString()
    itemView.listQuantity.afterTextChanged { 
        listused?.quantity = it.toInt()
        itemView.listUnitTotalPrice.text=listused.cost.toString()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks bro.May i know how to update the value receive from the user input back to quantity?